# How do you get the comments on a user's snippets using the gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab-api

In the [documentation for the gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html), it tells you how to get the notes for a snippet in a particular project by doing:

`GET /projects/:id/snippets/:snippet_id/notes`

However, this does not work for snippets that the user has created that do not belong to a particular project (i.e. those in `/dashboard/snippets`).

Is there a way to get the comments on these snippets using the gitlab api as well? I could not find anything in the snippets API docs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented, but you can access snippets without a project just by altering the endpoint:
Instead of `GET /projects/:id/snippets/:snippet_id/notes` try `/snippets/:snippet_id/notes`. Everything else about interacting with snippets appears to be the same, just the endpoint changes.